# English Grammar - Feeling good with

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I have a problem with EN grammar so i need a little bit of help.

So...

> From an early age, we are searching for a social circle and people we feel with.

**OR**

> From an early age, we are searching for a social circle and people feeling good with.

I have no idea which will sound better. Please help me. I don't know how to make it sound better.

Answer (score -1):

The first part should be:

> From an early age, we **search** for a social circle.

"Are searching" is an ongoing action, and while some people may search for friends their whole lives, I would suggest that we search until we find.

Now the tricky part, because neither of your sentences is natural and seem to be lacking some meaning. What, exactly, do we *feel*?

Some possible examples for what I think you might mean, given the context:

> From an early age, we **search** for a social circle and people we feel *comfortable* with.

Or, perhaps you don't need the word "feel" at all, and could just say:

> From an early age, we **search** for a social circle and people we *identify* with.